# Transform middle point with variable scale

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, geometry

I have got this code:

```
var Camera = function() {
  this.x;
  this.y;
  this.scale = 1.0;
  this.update = function(target, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, worldWidth, worldHeight) {
    this.scale = target.originalWidth / target.width;
    this.x = this.clamp(target.x - (canvasWidth / 2) * this.scale, 0, worldWidth - canvasWidth);
    this.y = this.clamp(target.y - (canvasHeight / 2) * this.scale, 0, worldHeight - canvasHeight);
  }
  this.clamp = function(value, min, max) {
    if (value < min) return min;
    else if (value > max) return max;
    return value;
  }
}
```

What it does is it makes the camera follow the target. it works pretty well but if the scale changes it is quiet off the position (more up and left to the center of the screen).

The Question is, how to calculate the x and y of the camera with respect to scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with experimenting I found out that if I do this:

```
this.x = this.clamp(target.x * this.scale - (canvasWidth / 2), 0, worldWidth - canvasWidth);
this.y = this.clamp(target.y * this.scale - (canvasHeight / 2), 0, worldHeight - canvasHeight);
```

It works just fine :)